# Unable to batch write two writes on the same Firestore collection in Angular project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working on an Angular project that uses Firebase Firestore to store data. I need to perform two write operations on the same Firestore collection as a batch write, but I am facing an issue with it. The second write operation is successful, but the first write operation fails without an error.

Here is my code:

```
async sendMail() {
    console.log('sending mail');
    const mail_1 = this.mailing_service.createEmail(
      ['test@test.com'],
      'test',
      'test'
    );

    const mail_2 = this.mailing_service.createEmail(
      ['test@test.com'],
      'test',
      'test'
    );
    try {
      const mail_doc_ref = doc(collection(this.firestore, 'email'));

      const batch = writeBatch(this.firestore);
      // set email to mail for applicant
      batch.set(mail_doc_ref, mail_1);
      // set email to mail for organization
      batch.set(mail_doc_ref, mail_2);

      await batch.commit();
      console.log('mail sent');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

The second write operation (for mail_2) is successful, but the first write operation (for mail_1) fails without error message.

hat could be causing this issue? How can I perform two write operations on the same Firestore collection as a batch write in my Angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue in my code is that I'm trying to write two documents to the same document reference (mail_doc_ref) within the same batch. Instead, I need to create two different document references for the two documents and write them to the batch separately.

Here's how I modify my code to fix the issue:

```
async sendMail() {
  console.log('sending mail');
  const mail_1 = this.mailing_service.createEmail(
    ['test@test.com'],
    'test',
    'test'
  );

  const mail_2 = this.mailing_service.createEmail(
    ['test@test.com'],
    'test',
    'test'
  );
  try {
    const mail_doc_ref_1 = doc(collection(this.firestore, 'email'));
    const mail_doc_ref_2 = doc(collection(this.firestore, 'email'));

    const batch = writeBatch(this.firestore);
    // set email to mail for applicant
    batch.set(mail_doc_ref_1, mail_1);
    // set email to mail for organization
    batch.set(mail_doc_ref_2, mail_2);

    await batch.commit();
    console.log('mail sent');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

In this modified code, I've created two different document references (mail_doc_ref_1 and mail_doc_ref_2) and written the two documents to them separately in the batch. This solved the issue I was facing.